# Passing HBase credentials in oozie Java Action

Tags: hadoop, hbase, kerberos, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I need to schedule an oozie Java action which interacts with secured hbase, so I need to provide hbase credentials to the Java action. I am using a secured hortonworks 2.2 environment, my workflow XML is as below

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="solr-wf">
    <credentials>
         <credential name="hbase" type="hbase">
         </credential>
      </credentials>

    <start to="java-node"/>
    <action name="java-node" cred="hbase">
        <java>  
             <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
             <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
             <main-class>com.test.hbase.TestHBaseSecure</main-class>
            <arg>${arg1}</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end"/>
        <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Java failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

I have also modified the oozie property to include HbaseCredentials Class

```
oozie.credentials.credentialclasses=hcat=org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HCatCredentials,hbase=org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HbaseCredentials
```

But I am not able to run the job it is throwing an error, below is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HbaseCredentials.copyHbaseConfToJobConf(HbaseCredentials.java:60)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.HbaseCredentials.addtoJobConf(HbaseCredentials.java:49)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.setCredentialTokens(JavaActionExecutor.java:1054)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:913)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1135)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:228)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:281)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:323)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CompositeCallable.call(CallableQueueService.java:252)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Other jobs runs fine, it's only the job with hbase interaction which is failing. I have included all the hbase jar in my lib directory, I am not able to figure out the issue.

**Updated workflow.xml:**

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="${appName}">
<credentials>
        <credential name="hbase-cred" type="hbase">
            <property>
                <name>hbase.master.kerberos.principal</name>
                <value>hbase/_HOST@ABC.COM</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>hbase.master.keytab.file</name>
                <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>hbase.regionserver.kerberos.principal</name>
                <value>hbase/_HOST@ABC.COM</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>hbase.regionserver.keytab.file</name>
                <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hbase.service.keytab</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
                <value>kerberos</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
                <value>dev1-dn2,dev1-dn3,dev1-dn1</value>
            </property>

            <property>
                <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
                <value>/hbase-secure</value>
            </property>
        </credential>


    </credentials>
    <start to="java-node" />
    <action name="java-node" cred='hbase-cred'>
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <main-class>com.test.hbase.TestHBaseSecure</main-class>
        </java>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>
    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Java failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: does my solution work for you?

Comment: yes it worked, but after adding the jars there were some connection issue ,i think it was trying to connect to some default host to get the token,i added some property in credential section and it worked , i am adding the modified credential section in the question

Comment: @RuslanOstafiichuk
I have configured as per documentation from oozie site, initially the job was submitted without any  issues in cmd prompt but in resource manager UI ,it’s does not shown anything like accepted or running state. Job run for long time and it was suspended due to exception in receiving Hbase credentials org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException and no issues were logged at this time .
Please suggest me is there any configuration need to set.?
Thanks,

Comment: @mathes i had the same issue,it was solved after adding the configuration section in hbase credentail section,refer the updated workflow.xml for required configuration,check it this works for you

Comment: @CTDex I am facing similar issue right now even after adding proper credentials property in workflow.xml.  Can you please share your Java code sample. I need to check if anything I am missing in the Java code.

Comment: @PadmanabhanVijendran there is nothing to do in java code it's the usual code you use to schedule any application. did you add relevant properties for the credentials, refer the updated workflow file. what is the error that you are getting??

Comment: @CTDex Same Error you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @CTDex Thanks.. Your credentials properties worked.. Thanks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution was tested on HDP2.2.8:

1. Copy to `/usr/hdp/current/oozie-server/oozie-server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib` the following jars:

   - hbase-client-*-hadoop2.jar
   - hbase-common-*-hadoop2.jar
   - hbase-protocol-*-hadoop2.jar
   - hbase-server-*-hadoop2.jar
   - htrace-core-2.04.jar
2. Restart Oozie server.

Answer (score 3):

These "credentials" are managed by the **Oozie service**, not by your job.

So, if HortonWorks had done a decent job of packaging their distro...

1. `hbase-common-*-hadoop2.jar` would have been deployed in
   `/usr/hdp/current/oozie-client/libserver/` on installation
2. that JAR would not conflict with other JARs over the definition of
   class *org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration*
3. and in the end you would be able to manage HBase
   credentials in Oozie

It is not the case for HDP2.2.4 as installed on our Prod cluster. Arghh. **The damn thing is broken in that damn release. You've got to manage the Kerberos ticket all by yourself**, downloading a keytab `<file>` from HDFS and creating the TGT before actually connecting to HBase. We've been there.

Have a look at [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211134/hbase-kerberos-connection-renewal-strategy/) for some insights about how it can be done.

Comment: Can you please try my solution?

Comment: Well, actually, no I can't -- moved to another assignment, don't have access to that Oozie + HBase + Kerberos setup any more.