# Authenticating to Kerberos enabled Hadoop Cluster Using Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I have Kerberos and have enabled Hadoop cluster. I need to perform HDFS operations using Java code.

I have `keytab` file and username.

Can someone please suggest how can I authenticate Kerberos using Java code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to use the **HDFS Java API** for a short-lived connection, then [`UserGroupInformation`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation.html) has a `loginUserFromKeytab` method.

If you want a durable connection (i.e. longer than the lifetime of the initial Kerberos TGT) then have a look at [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211134/hbase-kerberos-connection-renewal-strategy/33243360#33243360).

If you are interested in the dark side of Kerberos *(well, there is no other side anyway)* then have a look at the ["Madness beyond the Gate"](https://github.com/steveloughran/kerberos_and_hadoop) online book -- at your own risk.

~~~~~~

BTW there is an alternative to the Java API: the **WebHDFS REST service**. But on Windows you still need some Java code to create the Kerberos TGT *(using GSSAPI i.e. the Linux way, not SSPI i.e. the Microsoft way!!!)*, run the SPNEGO initial authentication, and retrieve the delegation token. At this point any HTTPS library will be able to handle the file operations using that token.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, then you can flag it as "accepted"  :-)