# Auto renewal of Kerberos ticket not working from Java

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

In my server application I'm connecting to Kerberos secured Hadoop cluster from my java application. On the application startup I do call

```
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI( ... );
```

I'm doing basic File operations using native `FileSystem` API like `FileSystem.exists()` and `FileSystem.delete()`

My application throws the following error after 24H. That's the expiry for Kerberos ticket.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:690)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:653)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:740)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1402)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:563)
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691071/1565509) answer, the Kerberos ticket should be auto renewed.

My application is using Java 8 and I came across [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10287).

But then looks like the [hadoop-common-2.7.1.2.4.2.12-1.jar](http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1.2.4.2.12-1/hadoop-common-2.7.1.2.4.2.12-1.jar) used by my application already has the fix. The source can be found [here](http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1.2.4.2.12-1/hadoop-common-2.7.1.2.4.2.12-1-sources.jar).

But still got the same error as the auto renewal was not happening. It was resolved only after calling [`UserGroupInformation.checkTGTAndReloginFromkeytab()`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.1/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation.java#L980-L983) before each action as suggested in the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691071/1565509) .But that was suggested only when using Rest APIs and not for RPCs and I hope native Java APIs use RPC only.

Why is the auto renewal not happening as suggested in the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691071/1565509)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is a known issue with automatic renewal not working correctly when using the `UserGroupInformation#loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI` method.  I am not aware of any known code fix within Apache Hadoop at this time.

Your solution to add a call to `UserGroupInformation#checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab` is a viable workaround.  I recommend that you stick with that for now and keep an eye on Apache Hadoop release notes to see if there is a fix committed in the future.

Comment: What is the know issue for UserGroupInformation#loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI? Can you point me to a Jira?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the hadoop-common jar used in your java application does not match with the server. Please modify your java application to use the same version of hadoop jars exists in server.