# Is kinit required while accessing a Kerberized service through Java code?

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I have a java application which needs to access Hadoop cluster to fetch a file at regular intervals(say, every 24 hours).

Since Kerberos protocol is enabled for protection on that cluster, I am using loginUserFromKeytab() method of UserGroupInformation class : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation.html.

Now, I know that kinit command grants a ticket-granting ticket to access any Kerberized service and this ticket has to be refreshed periodically(through kinit command). Now, my question is, is it required to run kinit periodically(from code) in combination with the above Java API for the code to work? Or will running it once be sufficient? Or is it not required at all.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `loginUserFromKeytab()` calls the java implementation of Kerberos to create a TGT, then it keeps it *private* to the current process. `kinit` calls the C implementation of Kerberos to create a TGT, then it makes it *shared* by storing it in a cache ("shared" by the Linux process owner only...)

Answer (score 3):

No. you don't need to run `kinit` periodically from anywhere if you are using the function `loginUserFromKeytab` with a valid keytab and username.

From [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation.html#loginUserFromKeytab-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

> Log a user in from a keytab file. Loads a user identity from a keytab file and logs them in. They become the currently logged-in user.

So everytime you call the method `loginUserFromKeytab` with valid parameters. It logs in the user.

Comment: So, is kinit required at all? I mean, do i not have to run it even once? As in, i couldn't find any info about the fact that the ticket is refreshed using the `loginUserFromKeytab` API.

Comment: You can use [`loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0/org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation.java) to get the details of the currently logged in User once the keytab has been successfully used to login.

Comment: Or if you really really want to play safe you can add one `Runtime.exec("kinit -kt .... ")` above your `loginUserFromKeytab`

Comment: That is my doubt. Currently I am executing `kinit` once, but `loginUserFromKeytab` is being executed repeatedly(for my purpose). But I want to know if ``kinit is required at all.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to `kinit`.

Comment: Thank you @philantrovert. Can you explain why? Is there any documentation which mentions how `loginUserFromKeytab` works?

Answer (score 3):

It's a long and complicated story. In short:

- if you request **explicitly** the Hadoop auth library to create a **private** Kerberos ticket with `loginUserFromKeytab()`, then that ticket is not renewable; you must launch a background thread to call `checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab()` from time to time, and it will re-create the ticket whenever it comes close to expiration
- otherwise the UGI will **implicitly** read the **shared ticket cache** to get an existing ticket; and it will also implicitly launch a background thread to **renew automatically** that ticket *(as long as it does not reach its end-of-renewal time -- at this point you are screwed)*

Some recommended readings:
 - [HBase Kerberos connection renewal strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211134/hbase-kerberos-connection-renewal-strategy)
 - [Should I call ugi.checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab() before every action on hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616676/should-i-call-ugi-checktgtandreloginfromkeytab-before-every-action-on-hadoop)
 - [Auto renewal of Kerberos ticket not working from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087997/auto-renewal-of-kerberos-ticket-not-working-from-java) *(i.e. there's a bug in the non-static methods of UGI)*

Comment: Also, a must-read if you really are serious about Kerberos on Hadoop: https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/