# What is the difference between relogInFromKeyTab and renewal of Kerberos ticket?

Tags: hbase, kerberos, hadoop2

I am running program which fetches the records from the secured (Kerboraized ) HBase .

And user principal I am using in my program has maximumlife of 30 Seconds and maximum renewal life of 1 Minutes .

And I am actually doing an experiment in the test program to understand how auto renewal works in Hadoop .

When I am making the thread sleep for every one minute before fetching the records it able to fetch the records .

My question here even though auto renewal of ticket is working fine .

Since the maximum renewable life time is 1 minutes when make the thread sleep for a miuntes and then fetches the records it still able to fetch the records How come this is possible as it violates the basic definition of the maximum renewable life time of ticket .

Is it because whenever it performs the reloginFromKeyTab before making an RPC call the life time of ticket it getting refreshed and advanced to the future time . i.e the current renewal time + maximum life time .

And what is the difference between renewal of ticket and reloginFromKey.

Comment: AFAIK the Hadoop-auth library does *not* honor the max-life parameter in the client `krb5.conf` file. And it uses the Java API, which does *not* support renewable tickets, so the max-renewal-life parameter has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616676/should-i-call-ugi-checktgtandreloginfromkeytab-before-every-action-on-hadoop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211134/hbase-kerberos-connection-renewal-strategy/