# Will the hbase kerberos token expired

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, kerberos

I have a spark streaming application, for every batch, I need to insert it to the hbase which is protected by kerberos. I found a solution, that is in the driver side I create a connection and obtain a token from that conn and then pass it to the executor. In the executor side, I decode it and get the token, in this way I can insert data to hbase successfully. This seems good, but my concern is that will the token expired? If so , how to solve it please?

My code snippet is

```
val ugi=UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principle,keytabfile);
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedAction[Unit]() {
  def run(): Unit = {
    conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
    val token = TokenUtil.obtainToken(conn)
    tokenStr = token.encodeToUrlString()
  }
})
```

in the rdd.foreachpartition,

```
val token = new Token()
token.decodeFromUrlString(tokenStr)
UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser.addToken(token)
```

Although I have searched a lot from Internet about this issue, but I did not found a good solution about this issue. The common answer to this question is

```
UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab();
```

But as my test, inside this method,

```
public synchronized void checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab() throws IOException {
if (!isSecurityEnabled()
    || user.getAuthenticationMethod() != AuthenticationMethod.KERBEROS
    || !isKeytab)
  return;
KerberosTicket tgt = getTGT();
if (tgt != null && Time.now() < getRefreshTime(tgt)) {
  return;
}
reloginFromKeytab();
```

}

The **isKeytab** is always false, so it will never execute the following code,I do not understand why this return false. So anybody can help me solve this question? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Congratulations! You have re-developed the Spark feature that automatically retrieves a "HBase token" and broadcasts it to the executors, whenever the Spark launcher detects a `hbase-site.xml` with Kerberos auth (since V1.3) You have also re-developed part of the standard HBase plugin for Spark, that was contributed by Cloudera and is available *(a)* in the CDH distro, *(b)* as an additional JAR for other distros using HBase 1.x, or *(c)* natively in HBase 2.x

Comment: But as I test, after several hours, the applications stoped at the insertToHabse method.And I got "javax.security.sasl.SaslException: DIGEST-MD5: digest response format violation. " exception, I suspect the token expired. I can renew the token, but I do not know when need I do it. I want to renew before the token expired, but when will the token expired

Comment: Did you simply SEARCH past StackOverflow questions? You might have found the answer by Chris Nauroth (Hortonworks) to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616676/should-i-call-ugi-checktgtandreloginfromkeytab-before-every-action-on-hadoop

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the java version. If you want to run a secured Hadoop cluster on JDK 1.7.0_85 or later, then you must run Apache Hadoop 2.7.0 or later.

To see this Jira issue [HADOOP-10786](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10786?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=14694182#comment-14694182)