# Accessing WebHDFS with multiple users

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, jaas, webhdfs

As the title says, is it possible to make a service that can handle WebHDFS request from multiple users on the same realm?

Im rather lost on this question, have searched the web and have found a lot of stuff but none seems to answer my question.

Im using SpringBoot to test this and so far I have made the following:

application.yml:

```
# HDFS properties
hdfs:
  user: user1
  config.path: file:/environment/hadoop-config/local.xml
  base:
    path: /user/${hdfs.user}
    data.path: ${hdfs.base.path}/data
```

-

```
@Bean("FileSystem")
public FileSystem hadoopConfig(
        @Value("${hdfs.config.path}") final Resource hdfsConfig,
        @Value("${hdfs.user}") final String hdfsUser
) throws IOException {
    final org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration config = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
    config.addResource(hdfsConfig.getInputStream());

    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(config);
    UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser(hdfsUser));

    final FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(config);
    return fileSystem instanceof WebHdfsFileSystem ? fileSystem : null
}
```

As you can see, this is a bean configured to work with one user only.

Exp. scenario. 
User1 has permissions to reads his data only and sends the reqest to list the data in /user1/data/foo, at the same time User2 has permission to read his data only and send to list the data in /user1/data/foo and gets denied.
Is this possible?

Can a JAAS file have multiple principals defined?
Exp.

```
client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    principal=“user1@EXAMPLE.COM”
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab=“/etc/secrets/user1.keytab"
    storeKey=true;

    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=true
    principal=“user2@EXAMPLE.COM”
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab=“/etc/secrets/user2.keytab"
    storeKey=true;
};
```

Plain java can work also i just need to understand the concept.
Thanks

Comment: Hadoop has the concept of "proxy users" i.e. privileged accounts that may issue requests on behalf of end users -- with some optional filtering on which users may be impersonated, and from which hosts the requests may be issued. That's how Oozie can run scheduled jobs on behalf of users. That's how  Zeppelin, Hue, Ambari View, Knox etc.  can access HDFS, Hive, etc. with Kerberos while users are authentified with LDAP.

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Proxy_Users

Comment: If you insist on using raw `UserGroupInformation` API, then don't use the default **static** object, but instead create multiple objects for different credentials -- cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815135/will-the-hbase-kerberos-token-expired snippet for example (that question is about low-level Spark dev and ticket renewal, but that's not the point)