# Can we user Multiple UserGroupInformation (ugi) objects to authenticate with kerberized hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, mit-kerberos

I need to authenticate two different HDFS cluster with different realms. But only one works fine when I instantiate another UGI object it gives the error

```
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(Principal , keytab path);
```

it works fine when I have single Service Principal Name

But when I have multiple SPN having different realm it gives an error

My User 1 and User 2 belongs to different Realms

SPN1 - "hdfs/user1@ALICE.ABC.COM"
SPN2 - "hdfs/user2@BOB.ABC.COM"

Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal principal name org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: No rules applied

But DEFAULT rule is there in both the cases

I also heard about Multiple UGI in this document https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/03/20/learning-kerberos-and-ugi

**Using Multiple UGI**

```
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(user, keytab);
```

But it also gives the same error how do I achieve these

Comment: `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab()` acts on the **static, unique** UGI that is sufficient in 95% of all cases. If you need to manage multiple Kerberos creds then you should note that `loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI()` clearly _**returns an UGI object**_ that you have to manage yourself with `doAs`, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815135/will-the-hbase-kerberos-token-expired

Comment: But your problem seems to be about using custom Kerberos-principal-to-Hadoop-user rules, to handle cross-realm authentication. Or maybe not. Please explain the context clearly, with examples of user principals, service principals, mapping rules, etc.

Comment: Note also tthat the `DEFAULT` rule applies only to UPN / SPN in the same realm as the Hadoop cluster. Which is not the case for you, apparently.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Yes, I need to authenticate my service with different Realms but UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab() allows rule for 1 realm only . I also tried to reset the ugi object and then change the configuration but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Honestly, your problem makes no sense. Your cluster _as a whole_ can belong to just one realm. But then, individual users from others realms can connect -- it simply requires "trust" (and some client-side configuration) between realms. In other words, cross-realm auth implies (a) the Kerberos back-ends and (b) the client. Not the Hadoop services.

Comment: And please stop using the word "user" when it is actually a "service" (with a SPN i.e. Service Principal Name `svc_code/host.fqdn^@REALM`)

Comment: Also, Kerberos does **not** work with IP addresses, only with canonical DNS names (i.e. the name matches the IP and the IP matches exactly that name). For obvious security reasons. There are config tweaks to change that but the Hadoop libs don't work well then.

Comment: Can we build cross-realm trust between both the realms in the same java programme so that both the configuration works well in the same JVM instance

Comment: without changing Kerberos backend?

Comment: You need trust between back-ends (one-way at least so that the cluster-side KDC accepts to create service tickets from a TGT created by client-side KDC) **plus** client config to get the `capath` between their own KDC and the cluster-side KDC. Maybe _BOB.ABC.COM_ > _ABC.COM_ > _ALICE.ABC.COM_ (implicit hierarchy traversal)

Comment: In short, what you want to do will require high-level expertise from your AD / LDAP admins and from Hadoop experts, plus days (or even weeks) of debugging. Google for `cross realm trust site:cloudera.com` to get a highly simplified overview.

Comment: I resolved it will Jass it can refresh the config . I have another issue with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147996/accesscontrolexception-simple-authentication-is-not-enabled-when-list-hadoop-co