# PriviledgedActionException (failed to find any kerberos tgt)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, hadoop2, mit-kerberos

I am connecting to hdfs by using kerberos as authentication mechanism,I am running a job which takes 3 days to complete,I am getting this error:

org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PriviledgedActionException as:user_name(auth:KERBEROS) cause:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]

I have also initiated crontab which does kinit by using the same keytab for every 1 hour but still am getting the same error and job fails to complete

please help me

Comment: Read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616676/should-i-call-ugi-checktgtandreloginfromkeytab-before-every-action-on-hadoop