# Hdfs sink connector and Kerberos

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, kerberos, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka Connect with some [HDFS sink connectors](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html) instances. They write in a secured hdfs with kerberos. Although connectors are working fine I have some questions about the security configuration. Below you can find the security aspects of the connector configurations:

```
      "hdfs.authentication.kerberos": "true",
      "connect.hdfs.principal": "my_custom_user@MY_DOMAIN",
      "connect.hdfs.keytab": "/etc/kafka/my_costom_user.keytab",
      "hdfs.namenode.principal": "nn/_HOST@MY_DOMAIN",
```

I wrote the configuration following the official documentation but I do not understand why I need to specify (all togethers) the `connect.hdfs.principal`, the `connect.hdfs.keytab` and the `hdfs.namenode.principal`. I know the ticket has to be created but I am not sure how the request is issued. I guess `connect.principal` + `connect.keytab` are used the get the TGT, but why do I need the `hdfs.namenode.principal`?

I thought `hdfs.namenode.principal` was required to get the Authorization Token and then obtain a Delegation Token, but currently I think it does not make sense, because, Kafka Connect cluster does not have installed the keytab for `hdfs.namenode.principal` so I understand if the `hdfs.namenode.principal` is used to create a TGT this should happen in Hadoop cluster.

could anybody shed some light on that?

Comment: maybe `connect.hdfs.principal` and `connect.hdfs.keytab` are used to create and login the UGI?

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34691071/2598606 answer explains very well waht RPC is and how it works. I have checked again HDFS sink code and I understand the following. `hdfs.namenode.principal` + `hdfs.namenode.keytab` are using to configure the `UserGroupInformation#loginUserFromKeytab` and `hdfs.namenode.principal`. I understand `hdfs.namenode.principal` is the principal for the namenode