# Kerberos kinit cache vs keytab in java to access secure HBase

Tags: java, hbase, kerberos, keytab

I am writing a java program to access seured HBase on kerberized cluster. My understanding is I can do it in two ways:

1. Login using principal name and password to create TGT in cache and
   use it to access the hbase.
2. Using keytab file to access hbase.

before I decide which approach I should take, I want to understand pros and cons of both options. I did google and found [this article](https://andriymz.github.io/kerberos/authentication-using-kerberos/) which explained how both options works. This post also pointed out that TGT from keytab can be renewed by calling `checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab` but it did not talk about renewal process for renewing TGT of kinit cache but I think it can be done using `renewTGT` property in jaas config(correct me if I am wrong). Another point from this post is that kinit cache is only good for short running application since we cannot renew TGT beyond 7 days.

I am leaning towards cache approach since I can securely keep username and password in keyvault and never have to worry about securing keytab. But limitation with this approach is as mentioned earlier, the max length of TGT(7days), I can't use it for long running jobs, at least that's what I understood(correct me).

If you can explain the difference between two or point me to a good article which explains both approach in details, that would be really helpful.

I have written below program to get TGT using username and password.

```
public static LoginContext kinit() throws LoginException {
    return new LoginContext("Client", callbacks -> {
        for(Callback c : callbacks){
            if(c instanceof NameCallback)
                ((NameCallback) c).setName(username);
            if(c instanceof PasswordCallback)
                ((PasswordCallback) c).setPassword(password);
            }
    });
}


public static void connectToKerberizedHBase(Configuration conf) throws LoginException, IOException {
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);

    LoginContext lc = kinit();
    lc.login();
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(lc.getSubject());
}
```

**Using it as below**

```
somemethod(){
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    loadHBaseConfigsFromProperties(config);//to load zookeeper quorum, port etc...
    connectToKerberizedHBase(config);
}
```

**JAAS Config file:**

```
Client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=false
    renewTGT=true
    useTicketCache=true;
};
```

The above mentioned article also talks about delegates using keytab which I didn't understand so please help me to understand if that is the right to create connection for long running jobs?

Comment: The Java implementation of Kerberos (part of JAAS) can consume a TGT from the Kerberos cache, but cannot renew it, cannot recreate it. Actually it _never_ writes anything in the Kerberos cache.

Comment: The Hadoop wrapper around JAAS (inside `hadoop-auth.jar`) does a lot of dirty things, including a lame way to renew a TGT found in the cache (using `kinit -T` in a sub-process, from a background thread) and a way to create/re-create explicitly a private TGT from a keytab

Comment: Note that the Hadoop UGI will not re-create a public TGT in the cache, and will not renew a private TGT (since it can be re-created anyway)

Comment: Hadoop services (HDFS, YARN, Hive Metastore, HS2, HBase) also use a delegation token mechanism to make Kerberos more friendly with distributed systems, but that's another story.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616676/should-i-call-ugi-checktgtandreloginfromkeytab-before-every-action-on-hadoop

Comment: Recommended reading: https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/kerberos_the_madness.html

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter: Thanks, Appreciate your response.