# HBase+Kerberos: UserGroupInformation logging in from keytab expires?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, kerberos, gssapi

We are using the method `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(user, keytab)`
to authenticate a Java program to write to a remote HBase cluster. When the application first starts up we are all good and it's talking to HBase happily.

The krb5.conf ticket_lifetime is set to 24 hours, and what seems to happen after 24 hours is that the "TGT expires" and we start seeing exceptions like this: `Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]`

We don't have any relogin logic. I always thought logging in from keytab shouldn't require us to write any additional code to relogin since it's handled by the RpcClient. But here are a few weird things:

1. Looks like some mechanism to relogin is kicking in but not doing anything, I'm not sure what method it tries to use `org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation Not attempting to re-login since the last re-login was attempted less than 600 seconds before.`
2. When initially authenticated via keytab, `isFromKeytab()` returns FALSE! I wonder if this is why it's not trying to use reloginFromKeytab() and tries to look at the cache?

Should we try to catch the exception and use `checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab()` or do something like this?

```
         if (UserGroupInformation.isLoginKeytabBased()) {
            UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().reloginFromKeytab();
          } else if (UserGroupInformation.isLoginTicketBased()) {
            UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser().reloginFromTicketCache();
          }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Jason

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211134/hbase-kerberos-connection-renewal-strategy

Comment: Thanks, @SamsonScharfrichter. Your other post was helpful.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter does checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab() rely on a jaas.conf? ugi.isFromKeytab() keeps returning false for me.

Comment: You should search the source code to be sure, but if I remember well, the `reloginFromKeytab()` methods *require* a previous `loginFromKeytab(keytab_file)` and a *private* Kerberos ticket. In other words, you set the keytab at login, then it is stored in the UGI and used whenever a *private* TGT has to be created/renewed/recreated. It will not work if the *public* ticket was used at login time.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter ended up using your shell suggestion for now. I'm on Java 8 and the relogin methods weren't doing it for me. i find some consolation in the fact that UserGroupInformation executes "kinit -R" directly in its renewal thread :D

Comment: check the compatibility matrix for **Hadoop version** (core libs) vs. **JDK version** -- you need at least Hadoop 2.7 *(or a patched 2.6 as in recent CDH releases)* for JDK 1.8 *(and later releases of OpenJDK 1.7 because they accidentally back-ported some 1.8 code in these)*; otherwise ticket renewal won't work due to vicious changes in the internals of JAAS.