# Running Spark job to query Hive HBase tables in a Kerberized cluster

Tags: apache-spark, kerberos

I am trying to run a Spark 1.6 job (written in Java) on Kerberized cluster.

Through the job I am trying to read data from a Hive table which uses HBase for its storage.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(context.sc());
hiveContext.setConf("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict"); hiveContext.setConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "false");
hiveContext.setConf("spark.sql.caseSensitive","false");
DataFrame df = hiveContext.sql(task.getQuery());
df.show(100);
```

I am using below spark-sumbit command to run the job on YARN:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class <Main class name> --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 1g --driver-memory 1g --jars application.json,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-client.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-common.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-server.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-hbase-handler.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml data-refiner-1.0.jar
```

I have already performed a kinit before running the job.
The job is able to communicate with Hive meta-store and parse the query.

```
17/04/05 06:15:23 INFO ParseDriver: Parsing command: SELECT * FROM <db_name>.<table_name>
17/04/05 06:15:24 INFO ParseDriver: Parse Completed
```

But when trying to communicate with HBase to get data it is failing with below exception:

```
17/04/05 06:15:26 WARN AbstractRpcClient: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)] 17/04/05 06:15:26 ERROR AbstractRpcClient: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'. javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)] at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:211) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.HBaseSaslRpcClient.saslConnect(HBaseSaslRpcClient.java:179) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupSaslConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:611) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.access$600(RpcClientImpl.java:156) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:737) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$2.run(RpcClientImpl.java:734) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClientImpl.java:734) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.writeRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:887) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection.tracedWriteRequest(RpcClientImpl.java:856) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1199) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.execService(ClientProtos.java:32765) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1627) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:104) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:94) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:107) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callBlockingMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:73) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AuthenticationProtos$AuthenticationService$BlockingStub.getAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationProtos.java:4512) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil.obtainToken(TokenUtil.java:86) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil$1.run(TokenUtil.java:111) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil$1.run(TokenUtil.java:108) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.runAs(User.java:313) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil.obtainToken(TokenUtil.java:108) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.token.TokenUtil.addTokenForJob(TokenUtil.java:329) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.addHBaseDelegationToken(HBaseStorageHandler.java:496) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.configureTableJobProperties(HBaseStorageHandler.java:441) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.configureInputJobProperties(HBaseStorageHandler.java:342) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveTableUtil$.configureJobPropertiesForStorageHandler(TableReader.scala:304) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$.initializeLocalJobConfFunc(TableReader.scala:323) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$anonfun$12.apply(TableReader.scala:276) at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HadoopTableReader$anonfun$12.apply(TableReader.scala:276) at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:174) at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:174) at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:174) at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:195) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240) at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:242) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:240) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:240) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:190) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:350) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:311) at com.hpe.eap.batch.EAPDataRefinerMain.main(EAPDataRefinerMain.java:88) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

The job runs fine when we query a normal Hive table and also on non-kerberized cluster.

Kindly suggest if we need to modify any configuration parameter/code changes to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you using principal file ?

Comment: `kinit` on an Edge Node obtains a Kerberos ticket on the Edge Node. So the Spark driver can authenticate against YARN to launch the job. But since you are running in **cluster** mode, the driver runs inside YARN, and does not have access to any Kerberos ticket. Neither have the executors.

Comment: There are a number of posts on StackOverflow about similar issues. So do your homework. But beware, the behavior of `--principal` and `--keytab` args depends on the Spark version (and build) you are using.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter
I tried using --principal and --keytab arguments with spark-submit command but it did not help. I also tried setting spark.yarn.keytab and spark.yarn.principal in the SparkConf instance but that too didn't help.

Interestingly I am able to query Hive OCR tables.

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

Comment: Did you have success with `yarn-client` mode? Did you try Spark 2.x? Did you try an explicit call to `loginUserFromKeytab()` in your code, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211134/hbase-kerberos-connection-renewal-strategy/33243360#33243360 ?